# Proving that two function coordinates of a parametric curve equals 1

Tags: calculus, derivatives, parametric

I am having difficulty with this question,

Note: This is not homework, It is from a practice test that I am using to study

Consider the curve:

$x(t) = \frac{1-t^2}{1+t^2}$ ;  $y(t) = \frac{2t}{1+t^2} $

The question is to prove that $x^2(t) + y^2(t) = 1$ for all $t$

I have no clue where to start, I think it has something to do with the unit circle, but I'm not sure

Also, to find the slope of a parametric curve, Am i correct in assuming that you simply differentiate both of them, plug in the x and y, and use rise over run?

Thanks!

Comment: Related : http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/591062/ellipse-problem

Comment: Thanks for the link, but I read through that and It seems like an unrelated problem

Comment: have you noticed the answer

Comment: Hmm, i'm not sure how I would apply the answer you gave over there to this question, any hints?

Comment: you can put $t=\tan\theta$ or use $$\left(\frac{1-t^2}{1+t^2}\right)^2+ \left(\frac{2t}{1+t^2}\right)^2=1$$

Comment: Okay, I tried that, and this is what I got:
$(1-t^2)^2 + 4t^2 = (1+t^2)^2$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:

Take t=cos $\theta$. You will get x=$\cos2\theta$ and y=$\sin 2\theta$. Eliminate $\theta$ by using $$\cos^2 \theta+ \sin ^2\theta=1$$